# Flutter I want to rebuild the list but can't be assigned

Tags: list, flutter, dart, rebuild

I want to pull the database in Flutter and list it with dynamic checkboxes as well, but I get an error. I was told to rebuild the list by referring to these links.
https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/issues/140

But two errors have occurred. *error: The argument type 'Future<List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable'*. and *error: A value of type 'List' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Future'*.

```
class Classname extends StatefulWidget {
  Classname({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  createState() => _ClassnameState();
}

class _ClassnameState extends State<Classname> {
  String test;
  String test2;
  String test3;
  bool isChecked = false;
  Future _data;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _data = List.from(getData());
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<List<Map>> getData() async {
    String path = join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'dbname.db');

    Database database = await openDatabase(path, version: 1,
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      await db.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE tablename(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, test TEXT, test2 TEXT, test3 TEXT)");
    });

    List<Map> result = await database.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM tablename');
    return result;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Map>>(
        future: _data,
        builder: (context, result) {
　　　　　　if (result.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
                child:
                    CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          if (!result.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: Text(
                  'no data'),
            );
          }
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                children: List.generate(result.data.length, (index) {
                  var data = result.data[index];
                  test = data['test'];
                  test2 = data['test2'];
                  test3 = data['test3'];
                  data.putIfAbsent('isChecked', () => false);
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Checkbox(
                            value: data['isChecked'],
                            onChanged: (bool value) {
                              setState(() {
                                data['isChecked'] = value;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                          Container(
                            child: Text(
                              test,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            child: Text(test2),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Text(
                          test3,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                }),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So I also tried changing the definition of the variable like `Future<List<Map>> _data` and so on but errors have occured. In the above case, *error: A value of type 'List' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>'*. and *error: The argument type 'Future<List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable'*.

Please tell how to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

The two errors are occured in this line:

```dart
_data = List.from(getData());
```

> *The argument type 'Future<List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable'*

The named factory constructor `List.of(...)`'s first param require a `Iterable`, but in your case, `getData()` is a `Future`, so the error occured.

> A value of type 'List' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>'

The `_data` field in your case is declared as `Future`, but it is assigned with a `List`, so the error occured.

To resolve them, don't use `List.of`. `getData()` is a Future, and `_data` just need it.

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _data = getData();
  }
```

And another way is that use `result` list. Remove `FutureBuilder` and change `Future _data` to `List _data`, and assign it's value in `getData` with `result`.

```dart
  List _data;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  Future<void> getData() async {
    String path = join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'dbname.db');

    Database database = await openDatabase(path, version: 1,
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      await db.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE tablename(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, test TEXT, test2 TEXT, test3 TEXT)");
    });

    List<Map> result = await database.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM tablename');
    setState((){
       _data = result;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _data == null 
        ? CircularProgressIndicator()
        : _data.isEmpty()
          ? Center(child: Text('no data'))
          : SingleChildScrollView(),
     );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't get the results I wanted, but I'll give it a try.